# MySQL 8.0 Deployment with Data Seperate

Tags: mysql, deployment, location

I have been running MySQL 5.X for several years. Just come to a new server and downloaded V8.0.11.0. I installed it and it asked me no questions about where to keep the data, it has put it all on the C: drive. I want to keep it separate to make backup easier. How do I make the data location move to another disk?
What I have tried:

- The old 5.7 method of stopping the server, moving the files, updating
  my.ini and restarting. You can't move the files (Access denied) and
  the server doesn't start if you change the my.ini file.
- mysqld --initialise --datadir="F:\MySQL\Data" (tried forward slashes and double slashes as well)
  I can't find any documentation! It's a pretty basic requirement so I'm guessing it must be documented!

Comment: Iám not sure if the data files for MySQL 8.0 are the same as MySQL 5.x best option would be to create a SQL dump with mysqldump on Mysql 5.x and import with mysql client program on MySQL 8.0.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I uninstalled MySQL and then ran the installer again. The first question is where do you want to put things! I take it all back, apologies for missing it!